# if and else if in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on a result project with table coursereg1sttbl .Lecturers are to input just scores and the grades are updated based on the total score  .  With if statement and else i was able to get this to work. This code is working well with php. How ever i want to write a job that will just do this at the sql level without php. So if score is 0 - 49 grade will be F and so on. How do i use sql for this . My main goal is to update table coursereg1sttbl SET grade = value of grade based on the conditions

````
<?php $sql = "SELECT * from  coursereg1sttbl WHERE matricno = '$matno'  AND registratioin_status ='1' ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{       
  //  Pharmacy Grading
  if($dptcode == 119 ){

      if($result->total_score >= 0 && $result->total_score <=49) $grade1='F';
      elseif($result->total_score >=50 && $result->total_score <=54) $grade1='E';
      elseif($result->total_score >=55 && $result->total_score <=59) $grade1='D';
      elseif($result->total_score>=60 && $result->total_score <=64) $grade1='C';
      elseif($result->total_score >=65 && $result->total_score <=69) $grade1='B';
      elseif($result->total_score >=70 && $result->total_score <=100) $grade1='A';
      else
      {
         $grade1 ='NA'; 
      }
  }   ?>  ```
````

Comment: Use `CASE` operator (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in a query immediately.

Comment: You are missing out on the security/stability benefits of a prepared statement when you directly inject variables into your sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to use SQL do this task (some people call it histogram-bucketing) is with `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` expressions in your query. It's the SQL way to do `if ... else if .... else if ... else`    (Notice this: like the rest of SQL it's declarative, rather than procedural like `if else`. You tell SQL *what you want*, whereas you tell Javascript or C++ or whatever programming language *what to do*.)

This query might do it for you.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total_score >= 0  AND total_score <=  49 THEN 'F'
            WHEN total_score >= 50 AND total_score <=  54 THEN 'E'
            WHEN total_score >= 55 AND total_score <=  59 THEN 'D'
            WHEN total_score >= 60 AND total_score <=  64 THEN 'C'
            WHEN total_score >= 65 AND total_score <=  69 THEN 'B'
            WHEN total_score >= 70 AND total_score <= 100 THEN 'A'
            ELSE 'NA' END AS grade,         
       *  
  FROM coursereg1sttbl
  WHERE matricno = '$matno'
   AND registratioin_status ='1';
```

Still, coding it this way seems verbose and error-prone.  Maybe somebody can invent a better way?

Comment: This looks interesting , i will  try it. How ever my main objective is to update same table and SET column Grade = what ever the grade is based on the conditions

Comment: @meetmec12: you can easily turn this to an `update` statement: `update coursereg1sttbl SET gade = CASE ... END WHERE ...`